# Run NUnit tests automatically from command line

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, nunit

I'm launching the NUnit gui from visual studio by setting the test project to start start nunit 2.5.3 as an external program.  That loads the tests into the GUI but I still have to manually click the run button.  Is there a command line argument that will have the tests run at the same time they're loaded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify `/run` on the [command line](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=guiCommandLine&r=2.5.3).

Answer (score 2):

---

### Help Syntax

NUNIT-GUI [inputfile] [options]

Runs a set of NUnit tests from the console. You may specify
an assembly or a project file of type .nunit as input.

Options:
/fixture=STR            Fixture to test

/include=STR            List of categories to include

/exclude=STR            List of categories to exclude

/config=STR             Project configuration to load

/noload                 Suppress loading of last project

**/run                  Automatically run the loaded project**

/runselected            Automatically run selected tests or all tests if none are selected

/console                Create console display for viewing any unmanaged output

/lang=STR               Language to use for the NUnit GUI

/cleanup                Erase any leftover cache files and exit

/help                   Display help (Short format: /?)

Options that take values may use an equal sign, a colon

### or a space to separate the option from its value.

### OK

Comment: +1 mostly because the nuint website is too slow to allow the lookup of documentation!