# How to integrate NUnit tests into a TFS 2010 build

Tags: nunit, mstest, tfsbuild, generic-test

What is the best way to integrate nunit tests into TFS 2010?  Is it via generic tests or is there a better approach to running them?

Ideally I'd like to have the granularity of one generic test per test assembly and have a way to surface the results in the TFS build report.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can run nunit tests from [command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043130/run-nunit-tests-automatically-from-command-line) and therefore you can automate these tests via your (Workflow) build template.

Since there aren't a lot of custom build activities available for TFS 2010 yet, you could write your own to make sure that it integrates better with the TFS Build Report.
[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/jimlamb/archive/2010/02/12/How-to-Create-a-Custom-Workflow-Activity-for-TFS-Build-2010.aspx) you can find some information about writing a custom build activity.

Another approach would be to create unit tests via Visual Studio. These tests will be automatically run when performing a build.

Comment: Yes I am currently wrapping nunit-console in generic tests but there is a lot of friction to it.  I shied away from the WF option due to the lack of integration with the build report.  I've also found this link http://blog.salvoz.com/2010/02/22/RunningXUnitFromTeamBuild2010AndPublishingResults.aspx which affirms what I feared and goes along with what you're saying about customizing the WF.  I was hoping for a better solution than the WF but this will suffice while we port over a sizeable amount of legacy tests.  Thanks and I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I've been playing around with WF as well and after a while it works pretty well. 
But I suggest to look again when the final version of TFS 2010 is there. Although I don't expect a lot of changes, there maybe some small improvements. Good luck further!!

Comment: Any update on this? Are you aware of any custom build templates for doing this, or do I still need to roll my own?

Comment: Personally I'm not using NUnit. We're using the Microsoft Test framework and those test assemblies are automatically executed during build. Maybe this will help you: http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/07/19/integrate-nunit-test-into-a-tfs-build/

Answer (score 20):

As of now (Oct 2011), the easiest way is probably via the NUnit activity that can be found in the [Community TFS Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20integrate%20the%20nUnit%20build%20activity&referringTitle=Documentation).

Answer (score 1):

Ian Battersby wrote a great [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20130507035827/http://blog.ianbattersby.com/2012/01/04/tfsbuild-2010-nunit-integration) how to set up NUnit tests for Visual Studio 2010.

Basically, you need to:

- download his build workflow template and set to your build definition
- install [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download) and [NUnitTFS](http://blog.strobaek.org/2011/10/18/more-on-tfs-and-xunit/) in your tfs machine
- add paths to installed directories in build process parameters
- set *Configurations to Build* setting in build process parameters
- change your NUnitTfs.exe.config with your collection name