# Functional tests in TFS 2010

Tags: .net, svn, testing, tfs, continuous-integration

We've got a range of applications written in different technologies (.net/php/java) for which we'd like to set up continuous integration.

All the source code is currently in SVN. There is already a few functional tests for web apps, using Hudson and Selenium.

I was asked to look at setting up TFS 2010 to run automated functional tests for .Net projects (web/winforms).

Could you please see my questions below:

1. Is it possible to run functional tests using TFS? From what I understand, I could either use it jointly with Test Manager 2010 (not sure how this would work with Continuous integration), or use build scripts directly in TFS (using MSTest.exe as a command line tool)
2. What is the best way to write functional tests for winform apps? Is it CodedUI tests?
3. Is setting up TFS just for automated testing worth the effort (cost is not an issue, they just want the most efficient testing system)
4. This will probably impact questions 1 and 3, but my team would like to keep all the code in SVN.. This argument alone looks to me like a good reason NOT to use TFS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If you write your tests using MSTest, it will be a lot easier. If you use [NUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478603/how-to-integrate-nunit-tests-into-a-tfs-2010-build) or something else, you can run it from the command line.

2) We use [NUnitForms](http://nunitforms.sourceforge.net/), a framework which extends NUnit. It's open source, really small, and you can do very cool things such as defining a handler method for when a modal dialog is shown. We use that to login automatically inside functional tests, for example. Not sure if you can do that kind of things with CodedUI.

3) If you are already using Hudson, it can run MSTest and NUnit projects. I would stick with it.

4) There is a [project](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/) which lets you use SVN and TFS together, but as the previous answers suggest, I'd avoid TFS.

Comment: 3) Thanks, I'll try to convince them to stick with Hudson.
2) I had a look at NUnitForms, but it does not look like it's maintained anymore, so I'll probably give a go with CodedUI.
4) svnBridge looks like it's to use a svnClient with a TFS server. In my case, we want all the sources to remain in a SVN server.

Comment: If `CodedUI` isn't up to the task (I decided that it wasn't when I saw that [it doesn't handle modal dialogs well](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsautotest/thread/a9c151dc-7f3e-4750-bb5d-37a34d1767a6/)) you might want to try [Project White](http://white.codeplex.com/discussions). Last code update is from August 2011, but the last forum post is from yesterday, so it seems that at least the site is active. I'm gonna try this project if NUnitForms fails me.